# Selecting panel data using respondent nummer because the panel data is unspecified

Tags: r, duplicates, extract, panel-data

I have a data frame which is partly panel data, looking something like this:

```
respnr country country-year year     a     b
1      France  France2000   2000       NA    NA 
3      France  France2001   2001     1000  1000  
2      France  France2002   2002       NA    NA
2      France  France2003   2003     1600  2200
3      France  France2004   2004       NA    NA
6      UK          UK2000   2000     1000  1000  
6      UK          UK2001   2001       NA    NA
8      UK          UK2002   2002     1000  1000  
9      UK          UK2003   2003       NA    NA
6      UK          UK2004   2004       NA    NA
11     Germany     UK2000   2000       NA    NA 
11     Germany     UK2001   2001       NA    NA
12     Germany     UK2002   2002       NA    NA  
14     Germany     UK2003   2003       NA    NA
12     Germany     UK2004   2004       NA    NA
```

I tried to extract the panel data by using the respondent number as follows:

```
df$panel <- duplicated(df$respnr)
dfp<- subset(df, df$panel == TRUE)
```

But I realised this only extracts one instance of the respondent number and hence does not create panel data.

Expected output:

```
respnr country country-year year     a     b
3      France  France2001   2001     1000  1000  
2      France  France2002   2002       NA    NA
2      France  France2003   2003     1600  2200
3      France  France2004   2004       NA    NA
6      UK          UK2000   2000     1000  1000  
6      UK          UK2001   2001       NA    NA
6      UK          UK2004   2004       NA    NA
11     Germany     UK2000   2000       NA    NA 
11     Germany     UK2001   2001       NA    NA
12     Germany     UK2002   2002       NA    NA  
12     Germany     UK2004   2004       NA    NA
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you show expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
       group_by(respnr) %>%
       #drops any group which only has one observation
       filter(n() != 1)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works and keeps the labels in place.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `table`

```
subset(df, df$respnr %in% names(table(df$respnr))[table(df$respnr) >= 2])
#   respnr country country.year year    a    b
#2       3  France   France2001 2001 1000 1000
#3       2  France   France2002 2002   NA   NA
#4       2  France   France2003 2003 1600 2200
#5       3  France   France2004 2004   NA   NA
#6       6      UK       UK2000 2000 1000 1000
#7       6      UK       UK2001 2001   NA   NA
#10      6      UK       UK2004 2004   NA   NA
#11     11 Germany       UK2000 2000   NA   NA
#12     11 Germany       UK2001 2001   NA   NA
#13     12 Germany       UK2002 2002   NA   NA
#15     12 Germany       UK2004 2004   NA   NA
```

---

`table(df$respnr)` returns a named vector

```
# 1  2  3  6  8  9 11 12 14 
# 1  2  2  3  1  1  2  2  1
```

OP want's only to keep observations with 2 (or more?) observations so we filter for those values

```
names(table(df$respnr))[table(df$respnr) >= 2]
#[1] "2"  "3"  "6"  "11" "12"
```

and finally create a logical vector to to `subset` the data:

```
df$respnr %in% names(table(df$respnr))[table(df$respnr) >= 2]
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly.